# accessing/handling bluetooth wireless keboard input(key press) in my ipad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

i have already done much googling on this **neither i found a tutorial/way to accomplish this nor find that it could not be acheived(so that i can assist my client ,it's not possible)**
we have requirement to integrate a bluetooth wireless keyboard in our existing ipad application.
some of the scenarios are....
suppose you are having a uibutton on the view.
then according to the requirement if user tap the key "entr/return" on the wireless keyboard
the result is same as tapping the button on view.if user tap the key "i" on the wireless keyboard the result is same as tapping the information button (UIButtonTypeInfoDark) on view.

Means we have to handl wireless keyboard key press events.

any idea/link/tutorial would very helpful for this situation. 
thanks!